# Firebase Messaging doesn't get token after deploying

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to use Firebase Messaging for notifications in the browser. In fact, it works locally but not when deployed on server.

It's used within an Angular5 application.

```
"@angular-devkit/core": "0.0.28",
"@angular/animations": "5.2.9",
"@angular/common": "5.2.9",
"@angular/compiler": "5.2.9",
"@angular/core": "5.2.9",
"@angular/forms": "5.2.9",
"@angular/http": "5.2.9",
"@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.9",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.9",
"@angular/router": "5.2.9",
"@angular/service-worker": "5.2.9",
"@firebase/app": "^0.3.4",
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.7",
"firebase": "^5.0.3",
```

Here is the code I used:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/messaging';

constructor(private http: HttpClient, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
          @Inject(FirebaseApp) private _firebaseApp: firebase.app.App) {
  const messaging = this.getFirebaseMessaging();
  messaging.onTokenRefresh(() => {
    messaging.getToken().then((refreshedToken) => {
      this.notificationTokenRefreshed$.next(refreshedToken);
    });
  });
}

getFirebaseMessaging() {
  return firebase.messaging(this._firebaseApp);
}

(...)

getNotificationToken() {
  const messaging = this.getFirebaseMessaging();
  return fromPromise(messaging.requestPermission().then(() => {
    return messaging.getToken();
  }));
}
```

I use the following `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file:

```
// [START initialize_firebase_in_sw]
// Give the service worker access to Firebase Messaging.
// Note that you can only use Firebase Messaging here, other Firebase libraries
// are not available in the service worker.
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.2/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.2/firebase-messaging.js');

// Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing in the
// messagingSenderId.
firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "abc",
  authDomain: "some-app.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://some-app.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "some-app",
  storageBucket: "some-app.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "123"
});

// Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background
// messages.
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
// [END initialize_firebase_in_sw]

// If you would like to customize notifications that are received in the
// background (Web app is closed or not in browser focus) then you should
// implement this optional method.
// [START background_handler]
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  // Customize notification here
  const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: 'Background Message body.'
  };

  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions);
});
// [END background_handler]
```

We have different behaviors:

- the `getNotificationToken` returns nothing (it doesn't return actually) for some users
- we have also this error for some users

  ```
  code: "messaging/unsupported-browser"
  message: "Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser)."
  stack: "FirebaseError: Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser).↵    at Object.Kt.a.INTERNAL.registerService.isSupported [as messaging
  ```

Did I miss something? How to properly implement notification handling using Firebase Messaging.

Thanks for your help!
Thierry